# RxJava2 map/flatMap with flatMapIterable

Tags: android, rx-java2

Here's what I am trying to achieve:
I have an API response say `myResponse`, which contains `List` of item. I want to iterate through each item through `flatMapIterable` which works fine. But before doing that I would like to check if API didn't return error or `List` size is > 0. I am not able to achieve this.
Here's the code what I have tried so far:

```
    // This works & I am able to iterate through each item
myApi.getData()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.flatMapIterable(response -> response.getData().getItems())
.subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Mobile>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(@NonNull Item item) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "item is => " + item.getItemName());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        Log.e("TAG", "processing completed");
                    }
                });
```

But I am not sure how should I use `map` or `flatmap` before `flatMapIterable`to check for any error. I am doing something like following without any success:

```
myApi.getData()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .map(response -> {
        if(response.getStatus() == 200) {
             List<Item> items = response.getData().getItems();
             if(items == null || items.size() < 1)
                   return Observable.error(new Throwable("No data!"));

             return Observable.just(response);
        }

       return Observable.error(new Throwable(response.getData().getMsg()));
     })
     .doOnError(Throwable::getMessage)
     .flatMapIterable(response -> response.getData().getItems());
```

Here on `flatMapIterable`, I get error cannot resolve getData(). because I believe It's not able to identify `response` as `MyResponse.class`. I am stuck here, please let me know how can I achieve what I want with RxJava2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `map(response -> {...})`  you have created `Observable` of `MyResponse`, that is why it does not compile. Just replace `map(response -> {...})` with `flatMap(response -> {...})` or add `flatMap(r -> r)` before `flatMapIterable`.

Comment: replacing map with flatMap worked :) thanks. But can you please tell me why it worked with flatMap & not with map?

Comment: Sure, your error handling code wrapped `MyResponse` into `Observable` so the type of items processed is now `Observable<MyResponse>`. That is why the code did not compile as `getData()` is method in `MyReponse` not in `Observable`. `flatMap` "removes" outer `Observable` so types are now as before adding error handling code.